# android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.View

Tags: android, api, view, classcastexception, rootview

`enter code here`I'm trying close popup when touch outside popup.My vode working API level 23+ .but not working API level 17.

Thank You in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkWQk.png)

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(dosy.app.yds.R.layout.toast_popup, null);
                        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                        txtToast=(TextView)popupView.findViewById(dosy.app.yds.R.id.textViewToast);
                        txtToast.setText(mWord);
                        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(widget);
                        final   View parent = (View) popupWindow.getContentView().getParent();
                        //dim the window in the background
                        final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        final  WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
                        p.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                        p.dimAmount = 0.2f;
                        wm.updateViewLayout(parent, p);
                        popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
                                    p.dimAmount = 0.0f;
                                    wm.updateViewLayout(parent, p);
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: try to use 'popupWindow.getContentView()' in place of 'popupWindow.getContentView().getParent()'

Comment: Hi Rahul, I'm try your advice. Now get "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams" exception,                                            line: WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams(); in API 23+ .                                                              So I cant touchoutside in API 17